# Calculate the exact position of button across different device sizes in Rico Dataset

Tags: python, json, android-layout

I've got a JSON view hierarchy of an android app as in the following from [here](https://interactionmining.org/rico):

```
{
  "activity_name": "com.funforfones.android.chicagocta/com.funforfones.android.chicagocta.MainActivity",
  "activity": {
    "root": {
      "scrollable-horizontal": false,
      "draw": true,
      "ancestors": [
        "android.widget.FrameLayout",
        "android.view.ViewGroup",
        "android.view.View",
        "java.lang.Object"
      ],
      "clickable": false,
      "pressed": "not_pressed",
      "focusable": false,
      "long-clickable": false,
      "enabled": true,
      "bounds": [
        36,
        84,
        1404,
        2392
      ],
      "visibility": "visible",
      "content-desc": [
        null
      ],
      "rel-bounds": [
        0,
        0,
        1368,
        2308
      ],
      "focused": false,
      "selected": false,
      "scrollable-vertical": false,
      "children": [
          ....
      ],
      "adapter-view": false,
      "abs-pos": true,
      "pointer": "2e18ce7",
      "class": "com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView",
      "visible-to-user": true
    },
    "added_fragments": [],
    "active_fragments": []
  },
  "is_keyboard_deployed": true,
  "requ

est_id": "1350"
}
```

It is said that **bounds** property specifies an element's bounding box within a `1440x2560` screen window. If I've got different widths and heights, can I approximate or calculate the exact position of that element bounded by the **bounds** attribute? I tried to get a quotient for smaller sizes (take 1920 by 1080 for example) by multiplying `1440*2560` and then dividing by `1080*1920` to get the quotient. Then I divided each coordinate by this coefficient, but it seemed to be wrong.  And maybe someone else knows in what format the coordinates are recorded here?

Comment: what does this have to do with OpenCV? if "nothing", untag OpenCV